# How to add add new packages in expo snack?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to use **expo-av** package in expo snack. However I know that after importing **expo-av** at App.js file. I have to add the **expo-av** at `package.json` file.

[image]

But I want to use packages like this one, in the `App.js` file without manually typing the version on `package.json` file.

### Is there any way to add packages in expo snack automatically after import? If I am missing this feature please let me know.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image]

Simply import the package in your js file and you will see a propmt asking you to install the dependency. Click on the `Add dependency` link and it will automatically add the package to your `package.json`.

You can read more about this at [Expo Snack Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/snack/#adding-a-library)